# How can I change Database columns display (label) in the views in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I did it in the past, but i don't remember how.

I'm using Bake to create some CRUD. In the view page (list page), it show all the columns with database field names. How can I hide some columns and change the displays?

Comment: Go into the templates and modify them then, as per documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Hun... but i remeber that have a way that i can define it in the "table class".

Comment: for CRUD, sure, but not for BAKE plugin. the first generates on the fly, the 2nd hardcoded. See https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp